# Batch and Count inifite stdin

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Assume you have some linux/shell command (i.e. `nc`) which outputs to the stdout some line-break separated strings. This commands never finishes with outputting (or outputs for a long time).

I'm searching for a command which I can pipe this output into and which gives me every x seconds a count how often which line occured.

So the command I'm searching for takes the stdin, splits on line breaks and counts how often each lines appears. Every x seconds, it outputs the stats and resets the counters to zero.

Does such a command/bash construct exist?

Comment: You can write a script, I think wc and grep are your greatest friends there.

Comment: wc and grep are not enough, I need something which considers the time and batches

Comment: I would not mix the timing and filter function. What I would do: write the filter (most possibly in awk just because the type of the aggregation suggests that), and write a timing job that sends a _very special_ line to netcat and awk, at the end of the pipeline, writes the sum and resets at the trigger of the very special line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

LAST_OUTPUT=$(date +%s)                                                         
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)                                                               
INTERVAL=30                                                                     
while read LINE; do                                                             
  echo $LINE >> $TMPFILE                                                        
  NOW=$(date +%s)                                                               
  if  [[ $(($NOW - $LAST_OUTPUT)) -gt $INTERVAL  ]]; then                       
   sort < $TMPFILE | uniq -c                                                           
   echo -ne > $TMPFILE                                                         
   LAST_OUTPUT=$NOW                                                            
  fi                                                                            
done                                                                            

rm $TMPFILE
```